# How to set string conditions for param to viewparams

Tags: geoserver, viewparams

SQL function like this `"SELECT * FROM myFunction('%FILTER%')"`, where `FILTER: and any_param >= 100` and `any_param < 1000`. When I run `geoserver/cite/wms?....&viewparams=FILTER:and any_param >= 100 and any_param < 1000;` I get message error `"org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog."` But, if I maked this param for default param, it is work fine. What is problem? Maybe I need screening any symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FILTER is a OGC protocol keyword, I'm guessing you are hitting some validation checks designed for it (the contents is supposed to be an XML document). Use a different variable name.